# Оповещение об ошибке php jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, логирование

Как сделать оповещение об ошибке php из лога в реальном времени с помощью jquery ajax

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - написать скрипт, читающий лог-файл при аjax-запросе. Клиентский скрипт должен периодически посылать ajax-запросы к этому скрипту. Чтобы посылать только новые строки, нужно хранить смещение в файле (фактически размер файла) при предыдущем запросе  - если файл стал больше, надо вернуть в ответе строки начиная от размера файла в предыдущем запросе и до конца фала, после чего сохранить новый размер фала лога.